# Can I group the textfields together and

Tags: ios, swift

Here's a snippet of my code below:

```
import UIKit

    class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet weak var passw: UITextField!

        @IBAction func LogIn(_ sender: UIButton) {


        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


            //password textField
            email.setCorner(radius: 12.0)
            email.setBorder(width: 1.0, color: UIColor.init(netHex: 0x85b51))

            // password text field
            passw.setCorner(radius: 12.0)
            passw.setBorder(width: 1.0, color: UIColor.init(netHex: 0x85b51))


    }
```

As you can see I'm setting the `textField` properties but the `textField`s are for the same view controller and they both have the same properties.

Is there a way I can set the properties for both `textField`s at once instead of setting the property for each `textField` one by one? Because I could have a view controller with many `textField`s.

Any help is well appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Create an array by code and/or use a `IBOutletCollection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
[email,passw].forEach {
    $0.setCorner(radius: 12.0)
    $0.setBorder(width: 1.0, color: UIColor.init(netHex: 0x85b51))
}
```

You can also create a custom class and assign to them in IB

```
class CustomTexf:UITextField {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setCorner(radius: 12.0)
        self.setBorder(width: 1.0, color: UIColor.init(netHex: 0x85b51))
    }
}
```

Comment: It works ! Many thanks ! . But please can you explain how you came about this especially  this "$0" , also when i tried this out i first got this error                      
 "Value of optional type 'UITextField?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: $0 is used in closures and in this case it refers to each value in your array. If it makes more sense, you can also do: 

[email, passw].forEach { (textfield) in 
    textfield.setCorner(radius: 12.0)
    textfield.setBorder(width: 1.0, color: UIColor.init(netHex: 0x85b51))
}

Answer (score 0):

If you have many components of a kind that need to be configured in the same way, it may be sensible to consider creating a sub class. Then, place your code for configuration in the sub class and use it throughout your app instead of the (original base class) component.

If it's a ui component, you can even make it @IBDesignable and then assign it in the InterfaceBuilder - then you can even see the looks of your customized component in IB.